# скачка файла pdf по ссылке, после скачивания файл не возможно открыть

Tags: php

размер и расширение файла правильные, скачка файла проходит на ура, но при попытке открыть файл (с помощью adobe reader или STDU Viewer) ошибка http://prntscr.com/jof5gp
файл рабочий, при прямом обращении к нему открывается без проблем, в чём может быть причина?

вот код для скачивания

```
function download($filename)
{
    if(file_exists($filename))
    {
        $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));
        switch( $file_extension )
        {
            case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
            case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
            case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
            case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
            case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
            case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
            case "mp3": $ctype="audio/mp3"; break;
            case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
            case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
            case "jpeg":
            case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
            default: $ctype="application/force-download";
        }
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false);
        header("Content-Type: $ctype");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
        readfile("$filename");
        exit();
    }
}
$path = "/";
if(isset($_GET['download']))
{
    download($path.$_GET['download']);
}

<a href="?download=file.pdf">Скачать файл</a><br />
```

Спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте закомментить все заголовки, кроме `disposition` и `length`

Comment: таже самая ошибка

Comment: размер файла в байтах скаченного соответствует тому, что на сервере? проблема мб в использовании относительного имени файла.

Comment: да один в один.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для pdf использовать тип **application/octet-stream**.

Comment: таже самая ошибка

Comment: Попробуйте сравнить скачанный файл с исходным побайтно. Например в Total Commander есть пункт меню «Сравнить по содержимому». Если есть отличия, то проблему нужно искать в передаче файла. Если отличий нет, то что-то на компе.

Comment: Спасибо! различаются, почему то в файл добавляется вся шапка сайта

Comment: Значит до отработки этого скрипта идет какой-то вывод в браузер.